# Configurar o GitHub

Tags: git, github

Gostaria de um auxilio de como eu faço para configurar o GitHub em minha máquina de Sistema Operacional Windows 10 32bits para subir os meus projetos.

Comment: vc ta falando do git ou do github software?

Comment: Olá Desculpe. Do Git com o Github.

Comment: Senhores moderadores e senhor @LINQ consultando a [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) vejo que esta pergunta está dentro do propósito do stackoverflow.
Vejam:
**1 - ferramentas comuns entre programadores**
**2 - problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software**
**3 - dúvidas teóricas sobre conceitos e práticas aplicados ao desenvolvimento de software**

Answer (score 3):

Instale o Git for Windows
https://git-scm.com/downloads

**Subindo seu projeto pela primeira vez:**

1. Entre na pasta raiz do seu projeto pelo prompt de comando
2. Crie o repositório local:

   ```
   C:\SeuProjeto> git init
   ```
3. Adiciona os arquivos ao repositório local:

   ```
   C:\SeuProjeto> git add .
   ```
4. Confirme todas alterações como commit:

   ```
   C:\SeuProjeto> git commit -m "Meu primeiro commit"
   ```
5. Adiciona seu repositório remoto (GitHub)

   ```
   C:\SeuProjeto> git remote add origin https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY
   ```
6. Empurre/envie (Push) todas as alterações para o repositório remoto (GitHub)

   ```
   C:\SeuProjeto> git push origin master
   ```

[Referência](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/)

Se deseja trabalhar em um projeto já criado no GitHub, veja isso:
https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/

Outra opção para o GitHub 'GitHub Desktop'
https://desktop.github.com/

Comment: Adicionei mais detalhes a resposta @Diego

Comment: Olá Edvaldo. Vou tentar configura da forma que você exemplificou e após eu escrevo se consegui.

Comment: Diego lembre-se de criar primeiro no site do GitHub o repositório.

Comment: Branches: master, develop, feature, release, hotfix.
Estou usando Git Flow (versão 32bits) para trabalhar de forma mais organizada. Veja isso em [Git Flow](https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/index.pt_BR.html)

Comment: Edvaldo você tem skype?

Comment: Olá @Diego, tenho sim. Veja em meu perfil:

Comment: @Diego [Tem 15 minutos e quer aprender o Git? Clique aqui!](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode, simplesmente, instalar o [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) e seguir as instruções dentro dele.

Comment: Olá Igor, você consegue me explicar os passos que devo seguir...?

Comment: @Diego não tem segredo. É só instalar e seguir o que software te falar para fazer. Ele mesmo vai te ensinar a usá-lo. Você não precisará usar linhas de comando nem nada nisso. Será tudo com interface gráfica.

Comment: Perfeito, vou tentar! Obrigado pelas informações